# Rails server fails because of uglifier gem

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, uglifier

When I try to load rails server, I get this error:

```
/home/jared/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:80:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'uglifier'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
from /home/jared/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
from /home/jared/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
from /home/jared/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
from /home/jared/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
from /home/jared/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
from /home/jared/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `require'
from /home/jared/thirteenthagecharbuilder/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/jared/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
from /home/jared/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
from /home/jared/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
from /home/jared/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
from /home/jared/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
from /home/jared/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/jared/thirteenthagecharbuilder/bin/rails:9:in `require'
from /home/jared/thirteenthagecharbuilder/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/jared/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/spring-1.6.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
from /home/jared/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/spring-1.6.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
from /home/jared/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/spring-1.6.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
from /home/jared/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/spring-1.6.2/lib/spring/client.rb:28:in `run'
from /home/jared/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/spring-1.6.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/jared/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/spring-1.6.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
from /home/jared/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/spring-1.6.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/jared/thirteenthagecharbuilder/bin/spring:13:in `require'
from /home/jared/thirteenthagecharbuilder/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:3:in `load'
from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

I have searched this question a lot, and every answer on stackoverflow I spy says "install nodejs", which I have done, and this hasn't fixed anything for me.

```
jared@machine:~$ nodejs -v
v0.10.29
jared@machine:~$ node -v
v4.4.4
jared@machine:~$ npm --version
2.15.1
jared@machine:~$ echo $PATH
/home/jared/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/bin:/home/jared/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@global/bin:/home/jared/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/home/jared/.rvm/bin:/home/jared/.rvm/bin:/home/jared/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/nodejs/bin
```

I have also added therubyracer gem to my gemfile. I bundle installed. At the end of my rope here, because, well, honestly the only advice I have seen from anyone regarding this problem is install nodejs, and usually the thread is marked as solved based on this, no further things I could try.

Running rails 4.2.5.1 on debian 8 (jessie) 64-bit, using rvm, ruby 2.4.0 installed.

EDIT: Since no one seems to want to take a crack at this, here is some more info from a rails dev I know who was also unable to troubleshoot the problem:

Adding

```
$stderr.puts e.inspect
```

Right above line 80 yields:

```
#<TypeError: wrong argument type Class (expected Module)>
```

And doing a search for uglifier to see if a class is being referenced somewhere in the project where it shouldn't be results in:

```
jared@machine:~/thirteenthagecharbuilder$ grep -r uglifier /home/jared/thirteenthagecharbuilder/
/home/jared/thirteenthagecharbuilder/Gemfile.lock:    uglifier (3.0.0)
/home/jared/thirteenthagecharbuilder/Gemfile.lock:  uglifier (>= 2.7.1)
/home/jared/thirteenthagecharbuilder/Gemfile:gem 'uglifier', '>= 2.7.1'
/home/jared/thirteenthagecharbuilder/config/environments/production.rb:  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
```

And lastly (for now), Line 7 of config/application.rb says

```
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)
```

Comment: What version of Ruby are you actually using? Not 2.4.0; no such thing. The best I can think of is upgrading to Ruby 2.3.1 (I assume you're actually on 2.3.0) and bundler 1.12.2 to see if that helps. I've run across bugs in both older versions recently, although I don't know that they're related to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I nuked ruby, long story short. I use rvm, so removing it was pretty easy, and I hadn't gotten much work done on the project anyway. So rvm and associated gems gone. I re-installed rvm, but this time used the option to install rails as well:

https://rvm.io/rvm/install

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails
```

This got me up and running. So I guess my best advice is to use the rails flag when using rvm.